# Error Build next js, Type error: 'carData' is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I have a problem with this component in next js, if I do the npm run dev it works, the problem is when I try to generate the next js build, it returns this error

```
./pages/marcas/[marca].tsx:66:30
Type error: 'carData' is possibly 'undefined'.
> 66 |                             {carData.cars && carData.cars.length > 0 ? (
     |                              ^
```

The code of the component is this

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import Header from '@/app/components/template/Header';
import Footer from '@/app/components/template/Footer';
import Content from '@/app/components/template/Content';
import '../../app/styles/globals.css';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { CarData } from '@/app/types/types';

const capitalizeWords = (str: string) => {
    return str.replace(/\b\w/g, (char) => char.toUpperCase());
};

const MarcaDetailPage = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { marca } = router.query;
    const [carData, setCarData] = useState<CarData>();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchCarData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(
                    `http://localhost:8000/api/cars/brand/${marca}`
                );
                const data = await response.json();
                setCarData(data);
                setIsLoading(false);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching car data:', error);
                setIsLoading(false);
            }
        };

        if (marca) {
            fetchCarData();
        }
    }, [marca]);


    return (
        <>
            <Header />

            <Content>
                {isLoading ? (
                    <div>Loading...</div>
                ) : (
                    <div className="container mx-auto py-8">
                        <h1>Cars {brand}</h1>
                        <div className="grid grid-cols-1">
                            {carData.cars && carData.cars.length > 0 ? (
                                carData.cars.map((car) => (
                                    <div key={car.id} className="p-4 border">
                                    
                                        <p className="mt-4 text-lg font-semibold">
                                            Modelo: {car.model}
                                        </p>
      
                                    </div>
                                ))
                            ) : (
                                <div>Error</div>
                            )}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )}
            </Content>

            <Footer />
        </>
    );
};

export default MarcaDetailPage;
```

I'm trying to use the carData interface to obtain an array of objects from the API and display them one by one. I think the error is in the map when I try to use the carData interface but I can't solve it

**CarData Interface**

```
export interface CarData {
    id: number;
    model: string;
    battery_kw: number;
    brand: {
        name: string;
        slug: string;
    };
    year_ini: number;
    year_end: number | null;
    power: number;
    sku_vehicle: string;
    initial_price: number;
    car_images: { id: number; ruta_imagen: string }[];
}
```

I have searched for help in google, stackoverflow, even chatGPT but I can't see the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [carData, setCarData] = useState<CarData>();
```

This `()` means that the initial value of carData is undefined. You can either initialize it with a value (in case the data was an array) or you can use optional chaining `carData?.cars`

```
{carData?.cars && carData?.cars.length > 0 ? (
  carData.cars.map((car) => (
      <div key={car.id} className="p-4 border">
      
          <p className="mt-4 text-lg font-semibold">
              Modelo: {car.model}
          </p>

      </div>
  ))
) : (
  <div>Error</div>
)}
```

Comment: Resolved, thxs !!!

Answer (score 1):

In `useState()` code you are not setting an initial state for `carData`, so it is undefined until `fetch()` resolves - hence the error during the build.

You can change the code to `carData?.cars` to specify that carData could be undefined (and cars array could not exists too).

Comment: Resolved, thxs !!!